# Qt Connect to WebSockets server

Tags: c++, qt, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Could someone point me in the right direction as to getting Qt to connect to a Node.JS running Socket.io server?

I've found examples of running Qt as a server, but none reading the data back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Qt there are atleast two ways of doing it. Either using blocking or non-blocking calls. If you use non-blocking calls the you "connect" your signals to the slots of the TcpSocket class you are using. The when some data has arrived you get an event/callback is triggered. This is not a complete example:

In your .h file declare the

```
#include <QtNetwork>
...
class MyClient : public QObject
{
  std::unique_ptr<QTcpSocket> tcpSocket_;
...
public slots:
  void readTcpData();
...
```

then in your .cpp file do something like:

```
MyClient::MyClient()
{
  tcpSocket_ = std::unique_ptr<QTcpSocket>(new QTcpSocket(this));
  connect(tcpSocket_.get(), SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readTcpData()));
}

void MyClient::readTcpData()
{
  QByteArray rawData = tcpSocket_->readAll();
  QString textData(rawData);
... do something with the received data.
}
```

To write data you can use tcpSocket_->write(...).
So whenever data arrives the readReady() signal triggers the readTcpData() function and you know there is "some" data available to read from the socket.
Hope it helps and answers your question. Good luck!

Comment: How does this handle handshakes and stuff? Is it automatic?

Comment: @James Yes. QTcpSocket handles that. It has several functions like connectToHost(...,...), waitForConnected(), close() and so on. Very handy. Use the QtAssistant and search for QTcpSocket, or go to the Qt website.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look and get back to you. I've upvoted for the time being :)

Comment: Doesn't Qt handle handshakes internally? I can't find anyway to re-connect with the given handshake parameters.

Comment: @James I have always called connectToHost(..,..) with the required parameters every time I wanted to reuse a QTcpSocket. So passing the required host and port when connecting is an issue for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [QWebSockets](https://github.com/KurtPattyn/QWebSockets/), which implements websockets using Qt. I also have build both client and server socket.io classes, which will be open sourced soon.